# How to skip inexact rename detection with git cherry-pick

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I have a about 10 commits I need to cherry pick from an old branch to a current branch on a large repo. Every time I run the cherry-pick command I get the following:

```
$ git cherry-pick -x 11a77a55bf
Performing inexact rename detection:   0% (438032/938483560)
```

I let it complete the first time, which took about about 10-15 minutes. But it does this for every commit I pick. Is there a way to prevent this, at least for the current command?

I tried setting a renameLimit but it didn't help:

```
git -c diff.renameLimit=1 cherry-pick -x 11a77a55bf
Performing inexact rename detection:   0% (1259342/938483560)
```

Comment: Try `merge.renameLimit=1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git cherry-pick` uses the merge machinery behind the scenes, which has its own configuration related to rename detection: [`merge.renameLimit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergerenameLimit).

```
git -c merge.renameLimit=1 cherry-pick -x 11a77a55bf
```

does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generally do this by running `git config merge.renameLimit 1`